# How do you “pivot” using conditions, aggregation, and concatenation in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, pivot, conditional-statements, concatenation, aggregation

I have a dataframe in a format such as the following:

```
Index    Name    Fruit           Quantity
0        John    Apple Red       10
1        John    Apple Green      5
2        John    Orange Cali     12
3        Jane    Apple Red       10
4        Jane    Apple Green      5
5        Jane    Orange Cali     18
6        Jane    Orange Spain     2
```

I need to turn it into a dataframe such as this:

```
Index    Name    All Fruits                                         Apples Total  Oranges Total
0        John    Apple Red, Apple Green, Orange Cali                          15             12
1        Jane    Apple Red, Apple Green, Orange Cali, Orange Spain            15             20
```

Question is how do I do this? I have looked at the groupby docs as well as a number of posts on pivot and aggregation but translating that into this use case somehow escapes me. Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `join`, create column `F` by split and pass to [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), last join together by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Name', sort=False)['Fruit'].agg(', '.join)
df2 = (df.assign(F = df['Fruit'].str.split().str[0])
        .pivot_table(index='Name', 
                     columns='F', 
                     values='Quantity',
                     aggfunc='sum')
        .add_suffix(' Total'))


df3 = df1.to_frame('All Fruits').join(df2).reset_index()
print (df3)
   Name                                         All Fruits  Apple Total  \
0  John                Apple Red, Apple Green, Orange Cali           15   
1  Jane  Apple Red, Apple Green, Orange Cali, Orange Spain           15   

   Orange Total  
0            12  
1            20
```

Comment: Thanks. If we added two more rows to the original dataframe to include another type of fruit for John and Jane, say, bananas the quantity of which we do not want to include in the totals columns, how would the sum function then be set up to take this condition into account?

Comment: @Zaphod I think the best is post new question.