# How do you groupby and aggregate using conditional statements in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, aggregation

Expanding on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65323569/how-do-you-pivot-using-conditions-aggregation-and-concatenation-in-pandas), I'm wondering how to add aggregation to the following based on conditions:

```
Index    Name    Item            Quantity
0        John    Apple Red       10
1        John    Apple Green      5
2        John    Orange Cali     12
3        Jane    Apple Red       10
4        Jane    Apple Green      5
5        Jane    Orange Cali     18
6        Jane    Orange Spain     2
7        John    Banana           3
8        Jane    Coconut          5
9        John    Lime            10
... And so forth
```

What I need to do is getting this data converted into a dataframe like the following. **Note**: I am only interested in getting the total quantity of the apples and oranges both of them in separate columns, i.e. whatever other items appear in a certain group are not to be included in the aggregation done on column "Quantity" (but they are still to appear in the column "All items" as strings):

```
Index    Name    All Items                                          Apples Total  Oranges Total
0        John    Apple Red, Apple Green, Orange Cali, Banana, Lime  15             12
1        Jane    Apple Red, Apple Green, Orange Cali, Coconut       15             20
```

How would do I achieve that? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `pivot_table` after extracting `Apple` and `Orange` sub strings as below:

```
import re
s = df['Item'].str.extract("(Apple|Orange)",expand=False,flags=re.I)
# re.I used above is optional and is used for case insensitive matching

a = df.assign(Item_1=s).dropna(subset=['Item_1'])

out = (a.groupby("Name")['Item'].agg(",".join).to_frame().join(
        a.pivot_table("Quantity","Name","Item_1",aggfunc=sum).add_suffix("_Total"))
       .reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)
   Name                                            Item  Apple_Total  \
0  Jane  Apple Red,Apple Green,Orange Cali,Orange Spain           15   
1  John               Apple Red,Apple Green,Orange Cali           15   

   Orange_Total  
0            20  
1            12
```

EDIT:
For edited question, you can use the same code  only except groupby on the original dataframe `df` instead of the subset `a` and then join:

```
out = (df.groupby("Name")['Item'].agg(",".join).to_frame().join(
        a.pivot_table("Quantity","Name","Item_1",aggfunc=sum).add_suffix("_Total"))
       .reset_index())
print(out)

   Name                                               Item  Apple_Total  \
0  Jane  Apple Red,Apple Green,Orange Cali,Orange Spain...           15   
1  John      Apple Red,Apple Green,Orange Cali,Banana,Lime           15   

   Orange_Total  
0            20  
1            12
```

Comment: Thanks. I would still need all items ("Banana", "Coconut", "Lime") included in the "Items" column, though. Could we still do a .join on the original "Items" column and then do the sum on the object created with the string extraction or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Zaphod could you please edit the question to include a full view of the expected output for clarity

Comment: Added the entire expected output to original question

Comment: @Zaphod ahh, try replacing `a.groupby("Name")['Item'].agg(",".join).to_frame()` with `df.groupby("Name")['Item'].agg(",".join).to_frame()` and use the same code and let me know

Answer (score 1):

*Edits*: fixed a bug.

To do this, before doing your groupby you can create your `Total` columns. These will contain a the number of apples and oranges in that row, depending whether that row's Item is  apple or orange.

```
df['Apples Total'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Quantity if ('Apple' in x.Item) else 0, axis=1)
df['Oranges Total'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Quantity if ('Orange' in x.Item) else 0, axis=1)
```

When this is in place, groupby name and aggregate on each column. Sum on the total columns, and aggregate to list on the item column.

```
df.groupby('Name').agg({'Apples Total': 'sum',
                        'Oranges Total': 'sum',
                        'Item': lambda x: list(x)
                        })
```

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't seem to return the sum of the actual quantities of each of the relevant items. Running the code, I get "5" in all rows of the "Totals"-columns

Comment: @Zaphod, you're right, I had a bug. I fixed it, and it's working now. I didn't run my code the first time, which is a bad idea, haha. But if I can make a suggestion, when asking questions about pandas dataframes, you should provide the code to generate them. I tried my hand at writing the answer without testing because I didn't want to spend 5 minutes typing out that dataframe. (I copied it from another answer on this post after seeing your comment).

Comment: For my understanding, how is the phrase "x.Item" and "x.Quantity" to be interpreted in the function? Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi, so the way the lambda syntax works is: it loops through every row in the dataframe. When we're in the loop, x is the row we're on, returned as a series object. So when you do x.Item, it's calling the Item element of the row. So for example if you did something like: row = df.iloc[0], this would return the 0th row the frame. If you then did: row.Item, you would be doing the exact same as what the lambda does with x.Item.

Comment: So, "Item" in "x.Item" refers to the value in the "Item" column in row x. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Exactly! So if we're in the zeroth row of the dataframe, which has Apple Red, then the bit `('Apple' in x.Item)` is true, so the lambda will return `x.Quantity`, which is 10, and therefore fills the "Apple Total" column with 10. But then when we're filling up "Orange Total" on the same row, the zeroth row, the bit `('Orange' in x.Item)` is false, so we return 0.

Comment: Thanks a bunce @Alan. So, to be clear in terms of the syntax, what is the difference, then, between `x.Item` and `x["Item"]`?

Comment: Pretty much no difference. The comparison between those two syntaxes appears in pandas both when pulling out columns from Dataframes (`df.col` vs `df['col']`) as well as pulling out values from Series. (In this case `x` is a Series). They both do the same thing. The only difference between them arises when column names are inappropriate to access via dot syntax.  For example, a column name like `"my items"` could not be accessed with dot syntax, because of the space. Or a column names `"columns"` could not be accessed, because `"columns"` is reserved by Pandas as a DataFrame object attribute.

Answer (score 1):

First Filter only the required rows using `str.contains` on the column `Item`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = StringIO("""Name;Item;Quantity
John;Apple Red;10
John;Apple Green;5
John;Orange Cali;12
Jane;Apple Red;10
Jane;Apple Green;5
Jane;Orange Cali;18
Jane;Orange Spain;2
John;Banana;3
Jane;Coconut;5
John;Lime;10
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,sep=';')

req_items_idx = df[df.Item.str.contains('Apple|Orange')].index

df_filtered = df.loc[req_items_idx,:]
```

Once you have them you can further pivot the data to get the required values based on `Name`

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df_filtered,index=['Name'],columns=['Item'],aggfunc='sum')
pivot_df.columns = pivot_df.columns.droplevel()
pivot_df.columns.name = None
pivot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()
```

Generate the Totals for Apples and Oranges

```
orange_columns = pivot_df.columns[pivot_df.columns.str.contains('Orange')].tolist()
apple_columns = pivot_df.columns[pivot_df.columns.str.contains('Apple')].tolist()

pivot_df['Apples Total'] = pivot_df.loc[:,apple_columns].sum(axis=1)
pivot_df['Orange Total'] = pivot_df.loc[:,orange_columns].sum(axis=1)
```

A wrapper function to combine the `Items` together

```
def combine_items(inp,columns):
    res = []
    for val,col in zip(inp.values,columns):
        if not pd.isnull(val):
           res += [col]
    return ','.join(res)

req_columns = apple_columns+orange_columns
pivot_df['Items'] = pivot_df[apple_columns+orange_columns].apply(combine_items,args=([req_columns]),axis=1)
```

Finally you can get the required columns in a single place and print the values

```
total_columns = pivot_df.columns[pivot_df.columns.str.contains('Total')].tolist()
name_item_columns = pivot_df.columns[pivot_df.columns.str.contains('Name|Items')].tolist()

>>> pivot_df[name_item_columns+total_columns]
   Name                                           Items  Apples Total  Orange Total
0  Jane  Apple Green,Apple Red,Orange Cali,Orange Spain          15.0          20.0
1  John               Apple Green,Apple Red,Orange Cali          15.0          12.0
```

The answer is intended to outline the individual steps and approach one can take to solve something similar to this

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Index,Name,Item,Quantity
0,John,Apple Red,10
1,John,Apple Green,5
2,John,Orange Cali,12
3,Jane,Apple Red,10
4,Jane,Apple Green,5
5,Jane,Orange Cali,18
6,Jane,Orange Spain,2
7,John,Banana,3
8,Jane,Coconut,5
9,John,Lime,10
"""))
```

## Getting list of items

grouping by name to get the list of items

```
items_list = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(["Name"])["Item"].apply(list)).rename(columns={"Item": "All Items"})
items_list
        All Items
Name    
Jane    [Apple Red, Apple Green, Orange Cali, Orange Spain, Coconut]
John    [Apple Red, Apple Green, Orange Cali, Banana, Lime]
```

## getting count of name item groups

renaming the temp df items column such that all the apples/oranges are treated similarly

```
temp2 = df.groupby(["Name", "Item"])['Quantity'].apply(sum)
temp2 = pd.DataFrame(temp2).reset_index().set_index("Name")
temp2['Item'] = temp2['Item'].str.replace(r'(?:.*)(apple|orange)(?:.*)', r'\1', case=False,regex=True)
    temp2
    Item    Quantity
Name        
Jane    Apple   5
Jane    Apple   10
Jane    Coconut 5
Jane    Orange  18
Jane    Orange  2
John    Apple   5
John    Apple   10
John    Banana  3
John    Lime    10
John    Orange  12
```

## getting the required pivot table

pivot table for getting items count as separate column and retaining just apple orange count

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(temp2, values='Quantity', columns='Item', index=["Name"], aggfunc=np.sum)
pivot_df = pivot_df[['Apple', 'Orange']]
    pivot_df
    Item    Apple   Orange
    Name        
    Jane    15.0    20.0
    John    15.0    12.0
```

## merging the items list df and the pivot_df

```
output = items_list.merge(pivot_df, on="Name").rename(columns = {'Apple': 'Apples
Total', 'Orange': 'Oranges Total'})
output
All Items   Apples Total    Oranges Total
Name            
Jane    [Apple Red, Apple Green, Orange Cali, Orange Spain, Coconut]    15.0    20.0
John    [Apple Red, Apple Green, Orange Cali, Banana, Lime] 15.0    12.0
```